# Formatting csv files

Tags: python

I'm currently attempting to import a list of numbers from a csv file as tuples, to look like this:

[(60, 20), (100, 55), (50, 40), (20,
70), (95, 85)])

```
def tuples(filename):
    import csv
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        rdr = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(rdr, None) 
        my_list = [tuple(filter(None, row)) for row in rdr]
        print(my_list)

tuples("tuple.csv")
```

However at the moment my output is:
[('60', '20'), ('100', '55'), ('50', '40'), ('20', '70', ' '), ('95', '85')]

How can I format my code to get rid of the quotation marks, and the empty field.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't want to "get rid of the quotation marks," you want to convert the strings to integers...

Comment: Sorry, worded it poorly, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehensions (which is neater but harder to understand for a beginner), Iterate through all the values and convert each element to an integer if one exists

```
my_list = [('60', '20'), ('100', '55'), ('50', '40'), ('20', '70', ' '), ('95', '85')]
my_formatted_list = [tuple(int(value) for value in _tuple if value.strip()) for _tuple in my_list]
```

Comment: so should I replace my_list with this variable?

Comment: Thank you, however do I have to manually input the list of tuples and assign them to  the variable _list?

Comment: It works btw, just curious

Comment: Just add it before the print

Comment: I mean can I import the values from my csv file, rather than typing them out and assigning them to my_list?

Comment: I just typed it out to show it works. you already have the values stored in the variable 'my_list' in your code. I just used the values you printed out. Your just need the second line of the answer

Comment: Yes! I understand now, really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

If you want those values in a list of integers you could do

```
intlist = []
for i in my_list:
    intlist += int (i)
print (intlist)
```

This would output [(60, 20), (100, 55), (50, 40), (20, 70), (95, 85)])

If you want to output the values seperately you could just loop over your list like that

```
for i in my_list:
    print (int (i))
```

If you want it on one line try something like that

```
line = ""
for i in my_list:
    line += i
print (line)
```

Comment: what would this do?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the imported values?

Comment: It would loop over the list,convert everything into intergers and add it into a new list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function like below:

```
my_list = [('60', '20'), ('100', '55'), ('50', '40'), ('20', '70', ' '), ('95', '85')]
[tuple(map(int, item[:2])) for item in my_list]
# Output: [(60, 20), (100, 55), (50, 40), (20, 70), (95, 85)]
```

**Explanation:**

`map(int, item[:2])`, `map()` is used to apply the function `int()` to each element of `item[:2]`.

`item[:2]`, to use only the 2 first elements of each `tuple` in `my_list`.